# Deploying Angular app to Apache server subdomain

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I'm trying to deploy my Angular 9 app to an Apache server at the subdomain level, but I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to configure my server and/or .htaccess file to make ngapp.domain.nl serve the Angular index.html file.

### Steps taken so far:

- I build my Angular app using `ng build --prod`, resulting in a distribution folder (dist/ngapp/)
- I used the control panel of my host provider to create a subdomain called 'ngapp'. This resulted in the creation of a subdomain folder. This folder is located at root/subdomains/ngapp. I placed everything that was included in my /ngapp/ distribution folder in it. See images of folder structure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTwKR.jpg).
- I configured my .htaccess as described in [Angular's documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration) and placed it in my /ngapp/ together with my distribution files. See the code below.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

The .htaccess code, however, is not configured for a subdomain, but I can't figure out how to alter this code to make it suitable. Nor do I know if I placed the .htaccess file in the correct folder.

Also I'm not sure if my DNS settings are as they should be.

### Subdomain behavior as is

When I visit my subdomain - ngapp.domain.nl - it shows a default page (created by my hosting provider) that states the subdomain is taken. It does this for every subdomain I place in front of my domain though.

**Any help would be appreciated :)**

*EDIT: added link to [images of folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTwKR.jpg)*

Comment: First of all, you need to map the subdomain to a folder in your server. This you should do while creating a subdomain. Please check that and confirm `ngapp.domain.nl` is properly navigating to that folder by typing `ngapp.domain.nl` in the browser

Comment: @JijoCleetus And how do I do this? This sounds a bit abstract to me.

Comment: You can do this from the Cpanel --> Create subdomain --> give a name for subdomain and choose an existing folder or create a new folder

Comment: Yes. This is what I tried to describe. I did create a subdomain like that. It can be found at root/subdomains/ngapp/ and this is where I've placed my Angular distribution files. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: If it shows the hosting partner's default page, then the folder mapping is not properly done. Please double check on the create subdomain area and confirm which folder it is mapped and you copied the angular build to that folder

Comment: I've added a link to images of my server folder structure. I don't see how any other folder structure would make sense, since the 'subdomains' and 'woonkamer' folders (I replaced 'woonkamer' by 'ngapp' in my post description as an example) are generated by my hosting provider.

Comment: you have to  set vhost setting in `/etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf file whenever this subdomain come document root will be `/var/www/html/ngapp` something like.

Comment: @felixboons i saw the folder structure. Please make sure this `/subdomains/woonkamer` this is mapped against the subdomain. Please refer this below image link for more details.
https://kbmedia2.names.co.uk/d2e/4bbdcc0e821637155ac4217bdab70d2e/cPanel_Domains_Create_Subdomain.png

Comment: @JijoCleetus [These are my subdomain settings](https://imgur.com/a/OZeN63X). I don't have access to cPanel - or any advanced settings for that matter - with this hosting subscription.

Comment: @felixboons Below document saying it will take 24 hrs to reflect the subdomain change.
https://www.transip.eu/knowledgebase/entry/31-creating-subdomain-your-hosting-package/#:~:text=Next%20to%20%27Your%20website%27%2C,%2C%20followed%20by%20%27Subdomains%27.&text=Create%20your%20subdomain%20by%20clicking,subdomain%20and%20hit%20%27Save%27.

Comment: Please read that doc and check your DNS settings also

Comment: @JijoCleetus Omg. I'm dumb. Better try again tomorrow then. Thanks and sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fix: removed auto-generated index.php that was in the /ngapp/ subdomain folder.

This index.php was loaded instead of my index.html. The index.php loaded the default provider page. Everything else was set up correctly.